# Значение * в CSS?

Tags: css, вёрстка

Есть объект body, который проецирует структуру сайта, а вот за что отвечает *?

```
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  font-family:'Roboto Slab', sans-serif; 
}

body
{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  background: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Дело в том, что в CSS существует концепция [наследования](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/inheritance), и все свойства делятся на наследуемые и ненаследуемые.

Таким образом, например, чтобы задать всем элементам в документе темно-серый цвет текста, нам достаточно правила типа `body { color: #333 }`, т.к. свойство color унаследуется всеми дочерними элементами, для которых не задан свой цвет.

А вот если мы хотим, чтобы для всех элементов, например, действовал единый принцип вычисления ширины и высоты, то должны написать правило сразу для всего множества всех возможных элементов: `* { box-sizing: border-box }` — потому что это свойство само не наследуется, а требуется очень часто.

Comment: body{color: цвет;} применится ни ко всем элементам ...

Comment: @Айболит «_не_ ко всем»

Answer (score 1):

Это универсальный [селектор](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors), который используется для применения стилей ко всем элементам DOM